# How to make 'document.addEventListener' in React fire after state changes?

Tags: reactjs

This is my code. The addEventLister will always fire before state is updated. Therefore, console.log(state) will be the previous state. How can I make it fire after the state updated? I thought addEventListener is supposed to fire after attribute event. Why is it different for this case?

```
export const MyComponent = () {
  const [state, setState] = useState();
          
  useEffect( () => {
    const handleClick = e => { console.log(state) }

    document.addEventListener("mousedown", handleClick)

    return () => {
      // Cleanup the event listener
      document.removeEventListener("mousedown", handleClick)
    }

  }, [state]);
  
const myFunction = () => {  setState(1)  }
   
return (
  <div onClick={myFunction}>Button</div>


)


}
```

Comment: Remove `state` from deps of useEffect

Comment: @meowww no I don't think is the correct suggestion. He will take a "missing dependencies" warning on `useEffect` (because he wants to print `state` value)

Comment: Thanks but this is only an example of my problem. In my real case, I need to keep 'state' in deps of useEffect.